# Generalizing Pythagorean Theorem to regular n-gon / semicircles extension?

Tags: geometry

We are all familiar with the regular Pythagorean theorem of $a^2+b^2=c^2$ where $a$ and $b$ are legs of a right triangle and $c$ is the hypotenuse. This formula can be visualized as turning each side of the triangle into a square and then saying the sum of the squares corresponding to the legs is equal to the square corresponding to the hypotenuse.

A potentially lesser-known theorem is that this generalizes to creating *any* regular n-gon from the sides, where the Pythagorean theorem we are familiar with corresponds to n=4. This proof is a relatively straight forward geometric proof where we split up the n-gon into n congruent triangles that share a vertex as the center (poor illustration attached lol) [image: Poor illustration here]

This allows us to show that for an arbitrary n-gon, we get:
$$a^2 \left(\frac{tan \theta}{4}\right)+b^2\left(\frac{tan \theta}{4}\right)=c^2 \left(\frac{tan \theta}{4}\right)$$

Obviously, we divide the constant out and we reach our original Pythagorean theorem. If we take This is interesting in it's own sense, but we can also do this with circles.

This is where I am hoping to get some insight on how we may connect this with $\pi$. My thought process is we may be able to find some sort of connection between the resulting constants of each term when inspecting the areas (hopefully??). I have two potential ways of thinking about this to offer some guidance to others, neither of which have let me make any connection.

1. We could construct semicircles with diameter equal to the sidelength and get the same result. This is straightforward and we get $\frac{\pi}{8}$. I don't think this method is very helpful as we don't construct the shape in a similar manner as we did previously.
2. We could consider taking the n-gon as $n\to\infty$. I believe this *should* result in a circle (?) (This part I am not sure of and would like clarity/correction on if possible). Thus $ \theta \to 90$, so $\frac{tan \theta}{4} \to \frac{tan 90}{4}$.

I don't know if there is anything in this but I was hoping to approach $\pi$ from an angle that may have not been done before and was looking for anyone to maybe give some guidance or find the next logical jump. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the $b$ and $c$ for an arbitrary $n$-gon?

Comment: I don't know if this is the generalization of the Pythagorean theorem you are looking for, but you can use ANY figure, not just regular $n$-gons or semicircles. This is a direct consequence from the fact that if two figures are similar with proportion $r$, it's areas are in proportion $r^2$.

Comment: @peterwhy b and c are the other sides of a right triangle. (Quantified at top)

Comment: @jjagmath that is a nice extension. I think I heard it before but your comment made me actually conceptualize it a little more as if were looking at things in $\mathbb{R}^2$.